# Excel manual calculation of worksheet other then active

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to set workbook for manual calculations for speed optimization. Mainly I want to calculate only current sheet after changes ware applied to it so I'm using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   Application.Calculate
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   ActiveSheet.Calculate
End Sub
```

But I have one sheet that I need to manually calculate two sheets- current, and second one. I tried different ways`Sheet(4).Calculate` or `Worksheets(4).Calculate`. It seems like only ActiveSheet.Calculate is working. How can I do it?

Comment: it should work. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834658.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want a specific sheet to calculate you need to remove `Application.Calculate`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub
```

And specify both sheets to calculate. A file with 3 sheets where Sheet1 is not calculated:

Sheet1 module (when Sheet1 changes):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Worksheets(2).Calculate
    Worksheets(3).Calculate
End Sub
```

Sheet2 module (when Sheet2 changes):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Me.Calculate
    Worksheets(3).Calculate
End Sub
```

Sheet3 module (when Sheet3 changes):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Worksheets(2).Calculate
    Me.Calculate
End Sub
```

.

Here are the utility Subs I use to optimize Excel settings for speed

Application level settings:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub fastWB(Optional ByVal opt As Boolean = True)

    With Application
        .Calculation = IIf(opt, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
        If .DisplayAlerts <> Not opt Then .DisplayAlerts = Not opt
        If .DisplayStatusBar <> Not opt Then .DisplayStatusBar = Not opt
        If .EnableAnimations <> Not opt Then .EnableAnimations = Not opt
        If .EnableEvents <> Not opt Then .EnableEvents = Not opt
        If .ScreenUpdating <> Not opt Then .ScreenUpdating = Not opt
    End With

    fastWS , opt

End Sub
```

Worksheet level settings:

```
Public Sub fastWS(Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal opt As Boolean = True)
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            setWS ws, opt
        Next
    Else
        setWS ws, opt
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub setWS(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal opt As Boolean)
    With ws
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False
        .EnableCalculation = Not opt
        .EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = Not opt
        .EnablePivotTable = Not opt
    End With
End Sub
```

Excel default settings:

```
Public Sub xlResetSettings()    'default Excel settings
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .EnableAnimations = False
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            With ws
                .DisplayPageBreaks = False
                .EnableCalculation = True
                .EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = True
                .EnablePivotTable = True
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Note: your code should restore setting to initial values when processing is completed